# `Trigger` autorunning when not supposed to

Tags: dynamic, manipulate

Recently I was trying to make something where one could vary the parameters and press play to see how the animation changed. However, when I tried running the code it would just start automatically. Even if I pressed pause nothing would happen. I managed to narrow the problem down and have made a simple example to illustrate the issue.

If I run the following code I get what I want. (i.e. press play and it starts. Press pause and it stops)

```
Clear[step,MyAnimation,dynamicVar]
step=0;
dynamicVar={1,2};
MyAnimation[nothing_,something_]:=Module[{},step++;something+{step,step}]
Manipulate[
    dynamicVar=MyAnimation[time,{1,2}];
    Dynamic@dynamicVar,
    {{time,1,""},1,\[Infinity],1,ControlType->Trigger,AnimationRate->2}
]
```

However, if I replace `dynamicVar=MyAnimation[time,{1,2}];`
 with `dynamicVar=MyAnimation[time,dynamicVar];` what I get is something which runs automatically and which one cannot not stop. (I know they give two different results, but the issue lies in the fact that I cannot stop it)

```
Clear[step,MyAnimation,dynamicVar]
step=0;
dynamicVar={1,2};
MyAnimation[nothing_,something_]:=Module[{},step++;something+{step,step}]
Manipulate[
    dynamicVar=MyAnimation[time,dynamicVar];
    Dynamic@dynamicVar,
    {{time,1,""},1,\[Infinity],1,ControlType->Trigger,AnimationRate->2}
]
```

Any advice on how to fix this problem?

Comment: You're creating an infinite recursion with `dynamicVar = MyAnimation[time, dynamicVar]` -- what are you really trying to do?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Every second I want `MyAnimation[time, dynamicVar]` to evaluate and assign the result to `dynamicVar`.

Comment: I'm glad you found my answer helpful, but if you wait longer (IMHO a day is good) to Accept an answer, you might get something *more* helpful.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard OK, I'll keep that in mind next time:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment:

> Every second I want `MyAnimation[time, dynamicVar]` to evaluate and
>   assign the result to `dynamicVar`

I believe you want something like this:

```
Manipulate[
  Dynamic @ Refresh[dynamicVar = MyAnimation[time, dynamicVar], TrackedSymbols -> {time}],
  {{time, 1, ""}, 1, ∞, 1, ControlType -> Trigger, AnimationRate -> 1}
]
```

Key elements are [`Refresh`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Refresh.html) and [`TrackedSymbols`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TrackedSymbols.html).

---

After a bit of reading it seems `Refresh` is extraneous here as one can use:

```
Manipulate[
  Dynamic[dynamicVar = MyAnimation[time, dynamicVar], TrackedSymbols -> {time}],
  {{time, 1, ""}, 1, \[Infinity], 1, ControlType -> Trigger, AnimationRate -> 1}
]
```

It might still be useful in your full application.